# Send notification from cron action in Odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I have a recurring CRON action in my app. When fired it updates some records in the database. I want to inform the creator of the record that it has been updated by the CRON task. I've tried many variations of the code below but no message is sent. There is no error thrown.

```
def _send_discuss_message(self, plan):
    recipient_id = plan.create_uid.id
    channel = self.env['mail.channel'].channel_get(
        [recipient_id])
    user_id = self.env.user.id
    message = ("Your plan %s has been validated") % (plan.name)
    channel_id = self.env['mail.channel'].browse(channel["id"])
    channel_id.message_notify(
        author_id=user_id,
        partner_ids=[recipient_id],
        subject="Test",
        body=(message),
        message_type='comment',
        subtype_xmlid="mail.mt_comment",
        notify_by_email=False
        )
```

Comment: Can't you just use a mail template?

Comment: @CZoellner I don't know. How would that work? I just want to send an internal message through Discuss. I don't want to send an email.

Comment: Yeah okay without email the channels should be the right way. Never used them so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message_notify` function expects a list of `partner_ids` to use to create a mail message record

You probably notified a partner with the same ID, try using the related partner ID instead:

```
recipient_id = plan.create_uid.partner_id.id
```

Comment: That works thanks. The user didn't receive a popup notification though. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @kpg have you been succesful with notifying a user and sending a popup notification?